# How to indicate that a substance is in a standard state?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, nomenclature

An superscript circle or Plimsoll  is typically used to indicate that a thermodynamic property is that of a substance in its standard state. On the other hand, when writing a chemical equation we typically use abbreviations to designate the state or phase of the substance, e.g. "g" for gas, "aq" for aqueous. Is there a common or standard way of describing symbolically that a substance is in its standard state, e.g. $\ce{Cl2(g,^\circ)}$ or $\ce{Cl2(\mathrm{std})}$, or is it necessary to spell out those conditions explicitly and allow the reader to infer that those are standard conditions, e.g. $\ce{Cl2(g,\pu{1 bar})}$?

Comment: What about the notation $M^\circ(\ce{compound,state})$ where $M$ is the thermodynamic property? I wouldn't add the pressure since the $^\circ$ already implies $p^\circ \equiv \pu{1 bar}$. If I need the temperature going on during the algebra, I use $M^\circ(\ce{compound,state};T)$. E.g., $G^\circ(\ce{Cl2,g};T_2) - G^\circ(\ce{Cl2,g};T_1)$

Comment: @MetalStorm That would be the way to do this if I was referring to the property, but I am attempting to describe the substance. The thought occurred to write "$\ce{Cl2^\circ}$" but rather than invent my own notation I thought I'd ask around. There is likely a convention, I haven't seen this asked here before though.

Comment: You don't react Cl2 at 1 atm with H2 at 2 atm. The conditions refer to the _reaction as a whole_ and should be marked as such.

Comment: Ohh, my bad. I haven't either, but I would use something like $\{\ce{substance}\}^\circ$ (e.g., $\{\ce{MnO4^-}\}^\circ$) as not to conflate with symbols relating to charge, radical, transition state, and so on.

Comment: @IvanNeretin But substances in solution in their standard state are (commonly) each at 1 M concentration. In the gas phase, standard state means each component at 1 bar. That does not refer to the pressure of the vessel under reaction conditions.

Comment: Regardless, the question refers to a substance in its standard state. Whether a reaction occurs is not relevant. What abbreviated notation is used, if any?

Comment: I'm not aware of a standard notation, so in case of need I'd probably invent my own.

Comment: On my browser (Chrome) using a circle in MathJax gives a silly small symbol, using o  instead  I think is much clearer, i.e G^\circ,  vs G^\text{o}, or $G^\circ$,  vs. $G^\text{o}$

Comment: @porphyrin my question is not really about aesthetics but ok. Since on the subject, an advantage of using the o is that it is ascii and readily transferred between editors, whereas the mathjax \circ symbol translates into nonsense when copy-pasted into a basic ascii editor. Which is related to my question, which is about using notation that is widely adopted and not confusing. As regards aesthetics I choose a balance between formatting effort and appearance. As mod I sometimes have to force myself to follow formatting guidelines more attentively.